# BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable For Loop

Tags: python

I am getting this error:

```
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I am running this code:

```
for count in range(len(videoFileClips)):
    videoFileClips[count] = VideoFileClip(videoFileClips[count])

finalRender = concatenate_videoclips(videoFileClips, method="compose")
finalRender.write_videofile('/Users/--/Desktop/test/render.mp4', codec='libx264',audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True)
```

It errors in the for loop. If you have any ideas please let me know!

Comment: Wild guess: you are trying to write to a file that you have already opened elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I have never received this error before, but I am pulling a significant number of files online. I believe this error occurs with a lot of requests and poor internet connection. Nothing to stress about, just need to try the program later.

It works when I give it some time/reset my modem.